# jQuery - How to add a class to a td tag

Tags: jquery, css

How would i go about adding a class to a td tag given the following table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="1"></td>
        <td id="2"></td>
        <td id="3"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I would like to add the class to the td with the id of 2.  The class name in my case is td_highlight.

Have tried a few different scripts with no luck.

Thanks in advance,
Billy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#2').addClass('td_highlight');
```

I am not including td in the selector because all your ids (by definition) should be unique in the page.

see the [relevant bit of documentation](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) for further reference.

Comment: u welcome - keep in mind @edl considerations about the ids though

Answer (score 11):

you can use `$('#2').addClass('td_highlight');` However, using a numerical value for an id may not play nice with some browsers. According to W3c:

`ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").`

You might try looking at:
http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the addClass() function:

```
$('#2').addClass('td_highlight');
```

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery('td#2').addClass('class');`

Comment: This is a dumb comment, but I felt compelled to at least bring it up.  Using the tagName#id approach breaks jQuery's internal mapping to getElementByID thusly slowing down the query.  Not a huge deal in this case tho...

Comment: if this is the case thanks for bringing it up; I never knew that